# Old php site not working on new IIS server, need to use GD library but can't figure it out

Tags: php, iis, gd, windows-7-x64

I have been developing our php based site on a development box that was set up when i started my new job a few months ago. I have just got a new dev box and am having some real trouble getting my IIS server to work with the site.

I am running windows 7 64bit and IIS7.

I get this error when trying to load the site:

```
Fatal error: Call to undefined function imagecreatefromgif() in filepath:// line:#
```

I have done some searching around and found that this particular function is part of the GD library and that i needed to enable it in the `php.ini` file. most sites were saying that i needed to uncomment this line `extension=php_gd2.dll` but it wasn't there, so i added it. I took the `php_gd2.dll` file from the old test box and put it in the folder specified as so

```
extension_dir ="C:\Program Files (x86)\PHP\v5.2\ext"
```

I should point out that I am using php5.2 by necessity, we use a library called ezpdf to create pdfs and it contains hundreds of references to `magic_quotes_runtime` the old dev box was actually running php5.0 but i couldnt find anything earlier than 5.2, and as far as i can tell the magic quotes things should be an issue before php5.3.

Anyway, using the php manager in IIS7, i can see that `php_gd2.dll` is enabled, however if i look at phpinfo() i can see no reference to GD.

No matter what i try i get the same error, does anyone have any ideas!?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

GD isn't JUST the .dll you load into php. there's a fair chunk of other code in other libraries that the php .dll references. You'll need the entire GD setup for it to work in IIS, not just the one php_gd.dll.

References to magic_quotes_runtime by themselves aren't 'bad' - a lot of libraries have to handle running under older PHP versions where magic_quotes is enabled by default, and do appropriate compensation for that fact. If ezpdf is, however, recreated magic_quotes behavior, then it's definitely time to upgrade versions or switching to something better. magic_quotes is deprecated for a reason, and re-enabling it in any way/shape/form is a bad idea.

Comment: Thanks, that shoved me in the right direction! the windows installer version of php is missing loads of files thats in the zip version, which i have now used, and now it works! I have inherited a system that revolves around ezpdf, which unfortunately seems to be a project on which development has ceased. There are no other developers in the company, and the job of switching to something else is too much for me in the short term. I would be interested in hearing peoples suggestions on things i can use to produce reports in pdfs in the future though! (so i can stop using antiquated software!)

Comment: The license is expensive, but I use pdflib (http://pdflib.com) for generating PDFs. It's not the most user friendly library, but it does allow you to do pretty much anything you want with a pdf.

Comment: Cheers, we are quite a small company so we will probably give that one a miss, I have stumbled across a few solutions including various services that take a HTML doc you direct them to returning a pdf, and FPDF looks promising as it is very similar to what we use currently but is actively being developed and is widely used (i think)